# Python throws "zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32" ONLY when I pass "D" as password

Tags: python, passwords, zip

I'm trying to create a Python script that tests passwords on password protected zip files. The only problem is that whenever I try to pass specifically "D" as the password, I get `zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32'`

To test it, I created `p.zip`, with the password `p`, and only one file called `p.txt` and ran this code:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("p.zip") as zf:
    password = "E"
    try:
        zf.extractall(pwd=bytes(password, "utf-8"))
    except RuntimeError:
        print("wrong password: " + password)
```

I just got `wrong password: E` which is what I expected.

However, when I run the EXACT same code except with `password = "D"` I get `zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'p.txt'`

I tried several strings such as `p`, `letmein`, `password1`, `DD`, `DDD` and they all work fine. ONLY setting `password = "D"` gives `zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'p.txt'`.

Does anybody know the reason for this or a possible fix?

Here's the full error on console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/argolis/workspace/zip-breaker/zip-breaker/script2.py", line 6, in <module>
    zf.extractall(pwd=bytes(password, "utf-8"))
  File "C:\Users\argolis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1594, in extractall
    self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)
  File "C:\Users\argolis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1649, in _extract_member
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
  File "C:\Users\argolis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
    buf = fsrc.read(length)
  File "C:\Users\argolis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 876, in read
    data = self._read1(n)
  File "C:\Users\argolis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 966, in _read1
    self._update_crc(data)
  File "C:\Users\argolis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 894, in _update_crc
    raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'p.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behaviour from the unzip protocol.  Sometimes an invalid password will pass the password check and be caught be the CRC check.  From [man unzip](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) (a Linux doc, but the algorithm is platform independent):

> The correct password will always check out against the header,  but  there  is  a  1-in-256
> chance that an incorrect password will as well.  (This is a security feature of the PKWARE zipfile
> format; it helps prevent brute-force attacks that might otherwise gain a large speed advantage  by
> testing  only  the  header.)   In  the  case that an incorrect password is given but it passes the
> header test anyway, either an incorrect CRC will be generated for the extracted data or else unzip
> will  fail  during  the  extraction because the ``decrypted'' bytes do not constitute a valid compressed data stream.

There is a Python [bug report](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/73925) where this is discussed.